# The name 'Properties' does not exist in the current context , with app.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I use in a project this to save a string connection in the app.config  :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup,  System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="ContaTroco.Properties.Settings"  type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<userSettings>
    <ContaTroco.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="servidor" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
        <setting name="banco" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
        <setting name="usuario" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
        <setting name="senha" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
    </ContaTroco.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

And in the code of C# i use this

```
        servidor = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        usuario = txtUsuario.Text;
        password = txtPassword.Text;
        catalog = cmbBancos.Text;  
        Properties.Settings.Default.servidor = servidor;
        Properties.Settings.Default.banco = catalog;
        Properties.Settings.Default.usuario = usuario;
        Properties.Settings.Default.senha = password;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

These codes works perfects in one project , but when i import the form to other projetco ( add existing item and i rename the namespace )  i have error on this part "The name 'Properties' does not exist in the current context", i have add the system.configuration reference to the project but the error con tinues. Thanks by any help.

Comment: You'll need to copy the Settings.settings file.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding a new dummy setting as follows:

[image: dummy setting]

then clicking the Save button. All errors saying "the name 'properties' does not exist in the current context" disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the app.config in the imported project, it might result in error. Inorder to have common config files, place these files in seperate folder, SharedConfigs and add shortcut to this file in required projects. Check [this](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSSharedFiles.aspx) out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, i have solved in one case copying all the files of the folder properties,
an in other caSE , i have change the namespace with refactor but dont work, and i must to create a new form and copy all the controls.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you don't have a Properties section of your application.  If you right click the project in solution explorer and choose to create a new settings file, you can can access it via Settings1."yourinfo".  Settings1 and yourinfo change depending on what you named your settings file.